# Dynamically determine second argument when the first argument is a key from an interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an interface like so that's passed as options to a module factory function:

```
interface FactoryOpts {
  name?: string
  radius?: number
  // many more entries...
}
```

For example:

```
factory({ radius: 10 })
```

Then I have an interface that defines the returned value from the factory. It has a few functions, but the one I'm stuck on is called "option" and can't see how I can avoid using "any":

```
interface ReturnedFactoryInstance {
  // I don't want to use "any" for the value, but I also don't
  // want to write a method for each options
  option(name: keyof FactoryOpts, value: any) => void
}

interface Factory {
  someProps: string
  (selector: HTMLElement|String, options: FactoryOpts): ReturnedFactoryInstance
}
```

Is it possible to dynamically determine the type of value? For example:

```
const instance = factory({ radius: 10 })

// Correct - this will compile
factory.option('radius', 10)

// Error - this will not compile
factory.option('radius', 'some string')
```

Is the only way to achieve this by making a function for each entry in `FactoryOpts`?

## Solution using Karol's advice:

```
interface FactoryOpts {
  name?: string
  radius?: number
  // many more entries...
}

interface Factory {
  someProps: string
  (selector: HTMLElement|String, options: FactoryOpts): ReturnedFactoryInstance<FactoryOpts>
}

interface ReturnedFactoryInstance<ValidOptions> {
  option: <Key extends keyof ValidOptions>(property: Key, value: ValidOptions[Key]) => void
}
```

You can then export a `Factory` e.g `declare const f: Factory` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface Factory<T> {
  option<K extends keyof T>(this: Factory<T>, name: K, value: T[K]): void;
}

type FactoryConstructor = <T>(arg: T) => Factory<T>;
```

Usage:

```
declare const factory: FactoryConstructor;

factory({ radius: 10 }).option('radius', 1);
```

See [TypeScript Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGKLAeygTwDwAqAfMgN4BQyymADmMJiHgNLIQAekIAJgM7IBrCDkwxkxABRgAFsF4AuNBmz5iAGmQg4AWwiLmGgG5wANgFc94gNrMAugEpFhzMG4BucgF9y5MDhoo6AhYuADCjLxgUGbB2MgAvMiERBJwUADmigT2CSRBIapEHuTcEAgmaSgIEWDI8LG4ivkq4SCR0Q3F9QUSpMhQcNzAZgrIAIwADMie9gB0tPSMEgDkA0Mjyxpj9m7IAPR7yICg5OTdKr39g8Ojk9NzCwwgK2vXm8jLMJiYyzv7h4ArZIB4P+Q4W0NGAJggAFp6Lo2FAoNhyEA).

Comment: Thank you! This answer is really close! In my case "this" isn't applicable, but the rest is. Updated the question with the solution for this specific case.